# SQL Server : counting time between two values in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-timestamp

I'm brand new to SQL Server (3 days experience so far) and I'm at a loss how to accomplish this outside excel, sorry if this is hard to explain.

Table example at bottom:

I have a table with timestamps every minute, a part counter, and error codes.
I currently am combining the part counts into 15 minute ranges and a total for that range with the below:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 15) * 15, '20000101') as Date_Time,
    MAX(Part_Count) - MIN(Part_Count) AS PartsMade
FROM 
    [SMP].[dbo].[33_TestImport]
WHERE
    [DateTime] >= DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, GETDATE()) - 24, 0)
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 15) * 15, '20000101')
```

Now I am trying to add into this, add one more row (for now).

PV_alarm will become a number, at that point I want to count time until part_count increases, pv_alarm could change multiple times in between when it first triggers and part_count increases again.

so:

- PV_alarm is naturally zero
- PV_alarm becomes nonzero <- start counting time
- PV_alarm changes multiple times, will end up at zero eventually
- parts count increments <- stop counting time, put time in this row

To be clearer: the table

```
DateTime              Part_Count    Alarm_Light PV_Alarm    Runtime_M
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-03-18 20:16:06.040 340946  0   0   127076
2020-03-18 20:17:06.040 340953  0   0   127077
2020-03-18 20:18:06.040 340960  0   0   127078
2020-03-18 20:19:06.040 340967  0   0   127079
2020-03-18 20:20:06.040 340973  0   0   127080
2020-03-18 20:21:06.040 340978  1   8   127081   <--- timer would start here
2020-03-18 20:22:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:23:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:24:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:25:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:26:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:27:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:28:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:29:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:30:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:31:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:32:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:33:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:34:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:35:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:36:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:37:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:38:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:39:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:40:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:41:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:42:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:43:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:44:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:45:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:46:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:47:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:48:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:49:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:50:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:51:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:52:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:53:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:54:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:55:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:56:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:57:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:58:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 20:59:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 21:00:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 21:01:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 21:02:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 21:03:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 21:04:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 21:05:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 21:06:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 21:07:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 21:08:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 21:09:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 21:10:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 21:11:06.040 340978  1   8   127081
2020-03-18 21:12:06.040 340978  0   0   127081
2020-03-18 21:13:06.040 340978  0   0   127081
2020-03-18 21:14:06.040 340978  0   0   127081
2020-03-18 21:15:06.040 340978  0   0   127081
2020-03-18 21:16:06.040 340978  0   0   127081
2020-03-18 21:17:06.040 340978  0   0   127081
2020-03-18 21:18:06.040 340978  0   0   127081
2020-03-18 21:19:06.040 340978  0   0   127081
2020-03-18 21:20:06.040 340984  0   0   127082    <---- timer ends
```

Results would be something like this, but its okay if it has to be its own result too that I can combine with the above select later

```
Date_Time               PartsMade   Downtime
2020-03-18 20:45:00.000 0   
2020-03-18 21:00:00.000 0   
2020-03-18 21:15:00.000 68          00:59:00
2020-03-18 21:30:00.000 97
```

Comment: This looks like an interesting question. Please show us the result that you expect, as tabular text.

Comment: i'll add the reply to the main post because I can't figure out how to format it in a comment

Comment: Thanks. Why does the third row as 59 minutes of downtime? I would expect the downtime to be distributed across the timeslots (so 0 minutes at 21h, 15 minutes at 12h15, and so on).

Comment: I want to know how long each issue takes to resolve, not a running total of how much downtime has accrued, not sure if there is a better way to do this either

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt.  See it at [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fddf9/46/0).

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT [DateTime], part_count, pv_alarm, case when pv_alarm>0 and (lag(pv_alarm) over (order by DateTime))=0 
               then 'START' else null end as State
from mydata as M1),
XX AS (
SELECT * from X where State IS NOT NULL
),
Y AS (
SELECT [DateTime], part_count, pv_alarm, (lag(part_count) over (order by DateTime)) as prev_part_Count
  from MyData as M2
),
YY AS (
  SELECT Y.[DateTime],Y.part_count,Y.pv_alarm,'END' AS State FROM Y 
  inner join XX on Y.prev_part_count=XX.part_count
  WHERE Y.part_count <> Y.prev_part_count
)
SELECT * FROM XX
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM YY
```

Discussion:

- CTE `X` assigns the value **START** to the column `State` in rows where pv_alarm has changed from zero in the previous row to nonzero in this row.
- CTE `XX` selects only those rows where `State` was assigned **START**. Strictly speaking this is not necessary -- it can be folded into YY and the final SELECT -- but it makes things clearer.
- CTE `Y` is a helper that brings the previous row's part_count together with this row's part count. You'd think it could be folded into `YY`, but the `LAG()` function has to be in the `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` clauses, not the `WHERE` clause.
- CTE `YY` takes the rows from `Y` where the part count changed, matches the previous part count to CTE `XX` to make sure we're keeping in the right span, and assigns the value **END** to `State`.
- Finally the non-CTE select just returns the **START** and **END** rows.

Output:

```
DateTime                part_count      pv_alarm        State
--------                ----------      --------        -----
2020-03-18T20:21:06.04Z 340978          8               START
2020-03-18T21:20:06.04Z 340984          0               END
```

This is not the full information you wanted, but hopefully you can finish it out from there.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation of the code! this looks great to start with!

Comment: If you have any ability to change the schema and functioning of your system, you'll get better query plans by replacing the `LAG()` expressions with materialized columns (i.e.  materializing `prev_part_count`, and flagging the start yourself when `pv_alarm' goes from zero to nonzero). And adding necessary indexes of course.